# Math - Pythag - Circles

Tags: math, geometry, pythagorean

Anyone know how to solve this?

[image: visual representation]

```
R = 10
Diameter = 2R
p1.x = 0    p1.y = 0
p2.x = -8   p2.y = -3

p3 = (x,y) = ?,?
p4 = (x,y) = ?,?
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. You have the `x` of `P3` and `P4`. They are the same as the `x` of `P2`. Also, you have the formula for the circle which is `x^2 + y^2 = R^2`. So, you can easily find the `y` of `p3` and `p4`.

```
p4.x = p3.x = p2.x = -8
p3.y = \sqrt(R^2 - p2.x^2) = \sqrt(100 - 64) = \sqrt(36) = 6
p4.y = -p3.y (= -6)
```

Hence, if `v` is the distance of `p2` and `p3`:

```
v = \sqrt((p2.x - p3.x)^2 + (p2.y - p3.y)^2) = \sqrt( 0 + (-9)^2) = 9
```

And if `v` is the distance of `p3` to `p4` it is:

```
v = |p3.y - py.y| = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Realised how easy it was after a little more thought... I need more patience...
Needs a bit of tweaking so that the calculation works in my 3D scene, but that's pretty much it. v = is dist between p3.y and p4.y

[image]

[image]